# Site works perfect in Mozilla but not in IE. Is my js file not compatible with IE

Tags: php, javascript, scripting, internet-explorer, mozilla

I'm working on a site written in PHP/MySQL. We have a form to reserve time on a calendar and it works great in Mozilla and stores the reservation to our database, but in IE you fill out the form and when you click the "Reserve" button to submit it and nothing happens. All I can think of is that my javascript is not working with IE. I have these lines in my .js file:

```
 resLenT = document.getElementById(resLenElem);

 resLenI = resLenT.selectedIndex;
 resLen = resLenI + 1;
```

where resLenElem is a drop-down box. These are the only lines that I can think of at the moment that might be causing trouble in IE. Does this all sound like I'm on the right track or am I way off base?

Comment: Do you get any errors thrown by IE? Stick a basic alert in and see what happens.

Comment: No, there is no errors, it just doesn't do anything. I will see if I can get a basic alert going though, thanks for the fast response!

Comment: IE and Mozilla treat combo-box differently, so I assume there is no probs in js.

Comment: ok, so would the problem be in my html? The php file I have generating the html creates the box like this:

Length of Reservation:<br />

<select id="resLen" name="resLen" style="border:1px solid #000000;padding:2px">
 <option selected>1</option>

 <option>2</option>

 <option>3</option>

 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>

 <option>6</option>

 <option>7</option>

 <option>8</option>
 </select> hr(s)<br /><br />

Comment: wow, that is impossible to read, ill repost that

Comment: Wow, a page that works in other browsers but not in ie? Unheard of! :-( Welcome to every web-dev's daily frustration. "Load time is 8 sec in Chrome, but 35 in IE. Please fix."

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
resLenT = document.getElementById("resLenElem");
```

notice the quotes around resLenElem

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply. The quotes actually cause Mozilla to do the same thing that IE is doing already. There is no errors thrown or anything, it just doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out. The problem is that I used the name and id "resLen" for my drop-down box in the php file. Then in my js file, I also called it "resLen". Mozilla was able to look at the js and php files as independent items, but IE was getting confused. Thanks again for all the fast replies! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So in the event that it is actually something in my html that is causing the IE failure, this is my html:

```
Length of Reservation:<br />
<select id="resLen" name="resLen" style="border:1px solid #000000;padding:2px">
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    </select> hr(s)<br /><br />
```

Am I messing something up there and IE isn't likeing it?

Comment: notice that the Id is resLen and not resLenElem as you posted before. so you would need to do: 

resLenT = document.getElementById("resLen");

Comment: oh, sorry i didn't clarify that. i use resLenElem because it is inside a function and "resLen" is passed in as the "resLenElem" element. but its all up and working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, IE seems not to make the difference between the name and the id of an element.